# Eclipse Android ADT bundle missing CVS

Tags: android, eclipse

Iv'e installed the Eclipse ADT Bundle, but under Window -> Preferences -> Team the CVS option is missing. It only has GIT. Is this normal? Also can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can fix it. I don't know whether its default or not. But you can just fix it by installing it. Just go to help menu and click install new software if the version is indigo you will have a link with indigo and with respective names for other versions. Wait till it loads and in the type filter text type as cvs and wait. After you get that just install and restart. know more [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-cvs/).

Comment: Can you please give details for that? I am unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 10):

On my ADT Bundle, under Help -> Install New Software...

I choose "Work with:" Juno

(I think Indigo is the previous release)

You should see a "Collaboration" section and in there is the "Eclipse CVS Client"

Select that and click next a couple of times.  Agree to the T&Cs and it will install.

After a restart, you can find the "CVS Repository Exploring" perspective underthe  "Window" menu.

*Note: After installing this myself, I noticed that it changed the appearance of the Eclipse workspace and I had to re-open all the files I had previously set up.*"

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, i went through lots of things and ways but unfortunately i was unable to plugin CVS with ADT bundle which is provided by Google.Inc.
    Then i came up with a solution. So what i did to resolve this issue, i set up Eclipse Kepler classic and plugin the ADT with eclipse kepler. Since eclipse kepler has built in CVS repository exploring options, i don't need to worry about that.I can get the code from the repository and good to go for coding...